# Label expression works on the series groups, but not on category groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In the chart I am building the series and categories labels need to be converted before displaying.
Conversion is trivial - replacing some charater with another and taking left X characters.
Entered into the properties of the Series groups/General/Label the expression works fine. The legend shows the converted series names. I expected that the same should be true for the categories groups and the converted labels should show along the X axis. But that is not working - the X axis labels are still raw column names from the underlying matrix where the chart takes data from.
The exact same expression is used on the matrix's column names and that works fine.

```
=Left(Fields!fiscalmonth.Value, 3)
```

That converts my November to Nov etc in the matrix, but not on the chart axis X.

Comment: Why don't you apply this transformation in dataset instead of doing it individually in chart elements?

Comment: More than one chart is based on the dataset and the other charts have to display full month names.

Comment: Why not create another column showing shortened version of the month name?

Comment: Why not? Because this would be a workaround instead of using correct function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct place for changing X axis labels is the Series Properties/Category Field expression. This is somewhat counter-intuitive, but works.

Comment: I don't quite understand this answer. Could you give more detailed description of the solution. Thanks.

Comment: What issue are you facing?