# SSRS line chart category group label not working

Tags: reporting-services

I want to group my X axis on the month number but display the month name.  I have this accomplished in my category group but it only displays as month number no matter what I put in the label property of the category group.  I tried to follow up with this post but didn't have enough reputation.
[Label expression works on the series groups, but not on category groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413801/label-expression-works-on-the-series-groups-but-not-on-category-groups)

Comment: So what is your group expression and what have you tried?

Comment: My group expression is on Month number but the label is set as month name.  I have tried even just setting the label as "Test" but the month number is still the only thing that displays.

Comment: When I said "what is the expression" I meant what I said.

Comment: Yeah, I think I answered that.  Here is the XML from the report for this:  <GroupExpressions>                      <GroupExpression>=Fields!MonthNum.Value</GroupExpression>
</GroupExpressions>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anybody ends up here, I found my problem.  I had the axis type set as scalar instead of category.  I guess when scalar is selected the label field isn't used.